# Freenas iscsi to VMware - Mount newly created disk to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, vmware, freenas, iscsi

We've installed Freenas with 4 WD RED drives. We have successfully enabled and configured the iscsi service for one of the disks.
On the other hand, vmware has succesfully created the iscsi adapter, found and connected to the iscsi target of freenas, created the datastore (slightly smaller than the actual disk) and created a new disk on the virtual machine.

Here comes the ugly part. Ubuntu recognizes the newly created disk and displays as follows:

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1879.0 GB, 1879048192000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 228447 cylinders, total 3670016000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

(note it reports more storage than set on the vmware disk 1750 GB)

Ohters have mentioned that the partition error is normal since it can't tell its not a normal disk.

After creating the disk in the Ubuntu VM I followed the following commands:
[detailed](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003940)!

```
mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdx
mkdir / New_Directory_Name
```

Edit fstab as following

```
/dev/sdb /New_Directory_Name ext3 defaults 1 3
```

and restarted but the error would come up:

[image]

Comment: It seems you are trying to create 1 filesystem over the full disk, without having partitionned it?  I believe you should  1)   `fdisk  /dev/sdb`   and create at least 1 partition of the proper type, and 2) then create a filesystem in that partition (ex: you created `/dev/sdb1` using fdisk, and then you `mkfs -t ext3  /dev/sdb1` to create a filesystem of type ext3 inside the /dev/sdb1 partition , and 3) you mount that partition on the appropriate mount point, using the entry you show in /etc/fstab (but with "/dev/sdb1" instead of "/dev/sdb" .

Comment: I just read the info you linked at : they indeed make you use the whole "virtual disk" instead of first partitionning it. It is possible, indeed.  `mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdx` should be in your case `mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdb`, and you should: `mkdir /New_Directory_Name`  (notice there is no space between "/" and "New_Directory_Name", as you are at this step creating a directory (inside your root (/) partition) that will be used as a mount point for your new filesystem), and the fstab entry you show is then fine. Run `fsck /dev/sdb` to check that filesystem (or `fsck /dev/sdb1` if you partitionned it)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems as if when I originally gave the mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdb command, i pressed no instead of yes. When i did for the first time, it just sent back to bash, instead of now that is working on it for a couple of minutes already. (In the meantime i was trying your suggestion with the partition, nevertheless another error was coming back: mkfs.ext3: inode_size (128) * inodes_count (0) too big for a filesystem...) Either way ill let you know how the redo turns out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Olivier's suggestion, the mkfs command hadn't been completed correctly so, in order not to face similar problems, just make sure that the file system of the disk you are trying to mount has already been build correctly using the mkfs command (and pressing yes!-depending on the size and the type of the disk, this might take several minutes-bare in mind that it won't be instant). Thank you Olivier for pointing out the issue.